# How to fix edge overlapping node in forest (increase distance between just two nodes)

Tags: beamer, forest, edge, overlap

I've the following tree made with `forest` package but unfortunately there is the edge to Z going through M. Why is that? I already tried to increase the `s sep` option but couldn't fix it. Does anybody know how to increase distance between these two nodes?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{forest}
                for tree={circle, draw, 
                 minimum size=1.5em,
                    inner sep=1pt, s sep=5pt,
                   align=center, top color=white},
                for leaves={rectangle}     
            [, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, minimum size=4mm
             [E
               [I
                 [L
                   [I
                     [G]]]]
               [U
                 [C
                    [H]]
                 [L
                   [E]]
                 [R
                   [O]]]]
             [F
               [L
                 [O
                    [G]]]]
             [G
               [E
                 [L
                   [B
                     [E]]
                   [D]]]]
             [M
                [I
                    [T]]]
             [Z
                [U]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Overlapping edge]

Comment: It doesn't look like `forest` is taking the edges into account. I'd use a different edge, maybe just doing `child anchor=north west` at the `Z` node is enough for this example.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You're right, it works fine for this example, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an option for level 1 like this: `if level=1{l=18mm}{}` to increase the level distance between root and the first children. This prevents from breaking the style of your tree (like it would be with `child anchor = north` imho).

[image: overlapping nodes and edges]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{forest}
                for tree={circle, draw, 
                 minimum size=1.5em,
                    inner sep=1pt, s sep=5pt,
                   align=center, top color=white,
                    if level=1{l=18mm}{} % <---------- This is it
                   },             
                for leaves={rectangle}              
            [, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, minimum size=4mm
             [E
               [I
                 [L
                   [I
                     [G]]]]
               [U
                 [C
                    [H]]
                 [L
                   [E]]
                 [R
                   [O]]]]
             [F
               [L
                 [O
                    [G]]]]
             [G 
               [E
                 [L
                   [B
                     [E]]
                   [D]]]]
             [M
                [I
                    [T]]]
             [Z
                [U]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```