# Latex forest edge with weird positioning

Tags: forest, edge

I'm facing a weird position of edge in standard forest code. Every edge is fine but the last one. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw, l sep=3em, s sep=0.5em, anchor=center, align=center, edge={-latex}}
    [Establishment
      [Agricultural,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}][,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      [Manual,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}] [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      [Service,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}] [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      [Profession,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}] [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      [Commercial,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}][,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      [Else,edge={dashed,black} [,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}][,draw=none,edge={dashed,black}]]
      ]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Adding `child anchor=north` into the `for tree` keylist will solve the issue.

Comment: Related: [Q671139](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671139)

Comment: Super thanks! The problem is solved.

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sašo Živanović said in a comment, adding `child anchor=north` into the `for tree` keylist will solve the issue.